# Do not working service and stop it when close the application (android)

Tags: android, service, foreground-service

My problem is that when I clear the program from the recent list, the service is stopped and does not work.

*This happens on Android 5 and it's no problem on Android 4.*
I even process the service in the manifest, but when the process is turned on, the service is not executed.(`android:process=":process"`)

**I will leave this service on the foreground on Android 5 and up after the page goes off, the service will be erased and nothing will happen.**

*In summary, I want to take my place and other tasks once every 5 seconds to display the user as Notification and I want to do this in the service.*

**start service in activity :**

```
if (!AppController.IsServiceRunning(TaxiService.class)) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                startForegroundService(new Intent(this, TaxiService.class));
            else
                startService(new Intent(this , TaxiService.class));
}
```

**in manifest.xml :**

```
<service
       android:name=".TaxiService"
       enabled="true" />
```

**in service :**

```
public class TaxiService extends BaseService {

    private Timer timer;
    private TimerTask timerTask;
    private long PERIOD = 60 * 1000;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        startTimer();
        startForeground(Variable.NOTIFICATION_ID_FOR_WAITING_STUDENT , Notification.ForegroundServiceNotification());
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        sendBroadcast(new Intent("ServiceIsKilled"));
    }

    public void startTimer() {

        //set a new Timer
        timer = new Timer();

        //initialize the TimerTask's job
        initializeTimerTask();

        //schedule the timer, to wake up every 1 second
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000, PERIOD); //
    }

    public void initializeTimerTask() {
        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                WaitingStudent();
                GetLocation();
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use Intent Service with method

```
startForeground()
```

if you want your service to continue to live while running

Comment: This method requires a notification. I want to display the notification to the user and the user can delete that notification from the list.**I want to see these happenings in the background of the program**

Comment: set isAutoCancelable(false) and user can't dismiss notification

Comment: I want to see these happenings in the background of the program

Comment: Like telegram, skype

Comment: if you want the work to be done even with the application closed, you must use notifications that the user will see. This is an Android system requirement

Comment: So apps like telegram work as notifications, and when the message is sent to the user, the notification is displayed.

Comment: I think GCM Firebase can help you with this case

Comment: So, in general, by no means can I do this without Notification?
You can hide a notification because some of the reminder programs are notifiable, but in their settings there is an option to hide the notification that as long as the user chooses the option, the notification of that program will be deleted and the notification of that program will still be available at that time. The desired user is displayed

Comment: I've updated my post so you can see and tell me the problem. Thanks